# Is incrementing an uninitialized int safe in C++?

Tags: c++, initialization

```c
int func() {
    int a;
    ++a;  // is this safe?
    printf("%d\n", a);
}
```

I know when I printf `a` I get undefined behavior, but is `++a` safe in C++ standard? Will this assign "another" uninitialized value to `a` without side effects (throwing exceptions or crashing the program)?

Comment: Even assuming reading uninitialised variables gives indeterminate values, if you don't know `a`'s value, how do you know it isn't `INT_MAX` (and the increment overflows)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using an uninitialized variable in anyways gives you Undefined behavior. So,
No incrementing an uninitialized `int` is **not safe** in C++.

Comment: Nit pick: *reading* an uninitialised variable is invalid. *Using* it otherwise is perfectly valid. How else would `int a; a = 3;` work? `a = 3` uses the uninitialised `a`.

Comment: Just out of interest, I've seen this mentioned elsewhere, but I've never found a reference to UB on uninitialised memory reads in the standard. Does anyone have a pointer? The only thing I've found is `Using a bool value in ways described by this International Standard as “undeﬁned,” such as by examining the value of an
uninitialized automatic object, might cause it to behave as if it is neither true nor false` which is, well, defined to be that way :)

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson C++11 [conv.lval] "If the object to which the glvalue refers is not an object of type T and is not an object of a type derived from T, or if the object is uninitialized, a program that necessitates this conversion has undefined behavior."

Comment: @hvd Thanks, I had to read that 5 times before being sure that's what it said, but that's definitely it :)

Answer (score 0):

Your program might not crash but it is certainly not safe. You should always initialize your variables. The worst that can happen is your program will appear to work but will crash at random times without you knowing the cause or simply behave in a strange way.

Answer (score -3):

What do you mean by "undefined behaviour"? In my opinion your program should print some int without any exceptions and so on.

++(uninitizalized int) is absolutely legal, I guess. It will just increment the current value, no matter whether the var was initialized or not.

But anyway, uninitialized vars are EVIL.

Comment: _undefined behaviour_ means that behavior is not defined by the Standard. In a nutshell, anything could happen.

Comment: If there's no undefined behavior according to you, why do you declare that uninitialized variables are evil?

Comment: @soon:  There is no "undefined" value for which incrementing could cause a problem.  While the value is not defined, the operation and results are defined and predictable.  Just because the value is not defined does not mean that it is not "safe" to increment.

Comment: @wallyk, I just explain what does UB mean. Robin asked about it in the begin of the answer. Also, the OP said about printing uninitialized variables, not incrementing.

Comment: @soon The OP asked about incrementing, not printing. From the question: "I know when I printf a I get undefined behavior, but is ++a safe in C++ standard?"

Comment: @hvd, _"What do you mean by "undefined behaviour"? In my opinion your program **should print** some int without any exceptions and so on."_ - So, as I understood, Robin asked about printing uninitialized variables(even if they are incremented, they are still uninitialized, aren't they?), which is UB.

Comment: @soon I think the OP asked whether incrementing an uninitialised variable would initialise it to an unspecified value, after which printing would be valid, because although unspecified, the variable would no longer be uninitialised. (That's actually pretty much how it works in C, for types that don't have trap representations: reading is allowed but not required to consistently give the same result, using the read value once to initialise the variable fixes the value, and it can then be read repeatedly giving the same result each time.)